# Does Splunk offer any such solution to make a call to SOAP REST HTTP URL and to test their availability?

Tags: rest, http, monitoring, splunk, smoke-testing

I need to create some kind of health check in Splunk that calls a Rest URL every hour and check if the response returns HTTP code 200 and send an alert in case there is an error like http code 400 or http code 500.

For example Splunk should make an http call to the URL of my application every hour and check if the URL of my application returns HTTP code 200. In case the response from the URL has a different code than 200 then send a notification email telling that something is wrong.

is that possible?
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the REST API Modular Input app at https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/1546/.

You can also create a Python program that checks the URL and reports on its health.  Schedule that program as a scripted input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the website monitoring app for Splunk, https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/1493/ to get the return codes for your endpoints